# Regex to find all curly brackets within a quoted string

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have a string:

```
test_str = 'This is the string and it "contains {0} a" few {1} sets of curly brackets'
```

I would like to *only* find `{0}` and *not* `{1}` in this example, that is, the brackets themselves and their contents, if only within a set of double quotes.

I've started to solve this by matching the portion in double quotes:

```
(?<=").*(?=")
```

See https://regex101.com/r/qO0pO2/1

but I am having difficulty only matching the `{0}` portion

How can I extend this regex to match `{0}`?

Comment: What's the `|` supposed to be for? You want to capture the whole thing, not either/or. And what are the lookarounds looking for? Also, given that this is how `str.format` works, there's probably some pretty efficient code in Python and/or its standard library for this.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I'll be using this for another purpose, i.e. adding a syntax definition to my text editor.  I had to first ensure that the brackets came between double quotes.

Comment: The only way to know if something is between quotes (and not outside) is to match all the quoted string (with single and double quotes) from the beginning until an opening double quoted string with `{n}` inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the quotes are balanced, you could use a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to check for an uneven amount ahead. If you know, that there is only one quoted substring, check if there occurs only one `"` until the end `$`

```
{[^}]+}(?=[^"]*"[^"]*$)
```

[See demo](https://regex101.com/r/lY4rU6/1). But if there could be any amount of quoted parts check for an uneven amount until end.

```
{[^}]+}(?=[^"]*"(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)
```

- `{[^}]+}` matches the braced stuff: literal `{` followed by `[^}]+` one or more [non](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated)`}` until `}`
- `[^"]*"` inside the lookahead  matches until the first quote
- `(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*` followed by zero or more balanced, preceded by any amount of non quotes
- `[^"]*$` followed by any amount of non quotes until end

[See demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/bU2sZ7/1)

Answer (score 2):

Remove the pipe `|` it will work great: <kbd>[Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wH9aM3/1)</kbd>

And here is for multiple char between `{}`

```
(?<=)\{[^\}]*\}(?=)
```

With <kbd>[Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wH9aM3/2)</kbd>

---

#### Update:

[This](https://regex101.com/r/wH9aM3/4) does the stuff :

```
".*({[^\}]*\}).*"
```

Comment: Only as long as the content of the braces is a single character

Comment: Sorry for changing my question - please see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can try word boundary `\B` and `lookarounds`- i.e.

```
>>>test_str="This is the string and it contains {0} a few {1} sets of curly brackets"
>>>re.findall(r'(?<=\B){.*?}(?=\B)',test_str)
>>>['{0}', '{1}']
```

See live <kbd>[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/jP7zJ3/3)</kbd>

But if your string does not have `word boundary` then try `lazy quantifier evaluation`

```
>>>test_str="This is the string and it contains {0} a few {1} sets of curly brackets"
>>>re.findall(r'{.*?}',test_str)
>>>['{0}', '{1}']
```

See live <kbd>[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/cV8eG2/2)</kbd>

---

**EDIT**

If you want only `{0}` then you have to use escape character(`\`) before braces, since braces are regex token-try as below.

```
>>>test_str="This is the string and it contains {0} a few {1} sets of curly brackets"
>>>re.findall(r'\{0\}',test_str)
>>>['{0}']
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be difficult to do in one regex, but it's easy with two:

```
from re import findall

# First find all quoted strings...
for quoted in findall(r'"[^"]*"', test_str):
    # ...then find all bracketed expressions
    for match in findall(r'\{[^\}]*\}', quoted):
        print(match)
```

or as a one-liner:

```
[match for match in findall(r'\{[^\}]*\}', quoted) for quoted in findall(r'"[^"]*"', test_str)]
```